# How can I find out with the Google Calendar API whether the user have enabled SMS reminders?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

My app saves events and their respective reminders to the users' Google accounts via the [Google Calendar API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). I would not want to offer the 'SMS Reminder' option for those users whom have not enabled this functionality and verified their phone number on their Google account.

**I tried this so far:**
I inserted an event with an SMS reminder for a Google account which does not have SMS reminders enabled.
Result:The SMS reminder did get registered/saved (as the Event object returned by the API response did have the SMS reminder), but this SMS reminder was not visible in the calendar until the user configured mobile setup. In other words SMS events can be added, but they are ignored until the user's account is provisioned, and my app has no way of knowing that.

Comment: Please add more information, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you added the android and a bunch of google tags, so I'll bite (take the bait)!

Have the endusers asked for 'SMS reminders'? Or are you offering 'SMS reminders' to 'only' your endusers that have Android devices? Why offer 'SMS' reminders, when Google Now (Android 4.1 or 4.1.2+) is now available that offers 'true' (non-old-technology-SMS) reminders?

My app pushes events to one calendar, shared by all personnel 'interested', set reminders for each event in the shared calendar settings (I think), and those that have access to the shared calendars...get Google Now reminders (1hr, 2hr, 12hr, 24hr) on every event.

Go with Google Now instead of older (SMS) technology. Google Now is so much more user-friendly. My app sends google maps URLs in the event description along with customer contact info, etc..., and if you set a valid location in Where, in your event, then Google Now will inform the Android enduser 'what time to leave to arrive on time' (my brother told me about that, and wanted my app to add the location data in the Where of the event), and they/we are loving Google Now reminders on our Android devices.

we are one google/android-happy family. :)